# Can someone help solving the 4th order exponential equation subject to the constraint equations?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Let

$$f(x)=\exp\left(\sum_{i=0}^4\theta_ix^i\right).$$

Given the following constraints:

1. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=1$
2. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)dx=0$
3. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2f(x)dx=1$
4. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^3f(x)dx=s$
5. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^4f(x)dx=k$

where $k$ and $s$ are constants, how one would proceed in finding the parameters $\theta_i$ which satisfy these constraints?

Answer (score 0):

your question reminds me a Gaussian distribution,
\begin{align}
X\sim G(\mu=0,\sigma=1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}
\end{align}

note that the first integral equals to 1 (due to the nature of density function). The second one is the expectation of the random variable that is zero.  the third one is variance that is one. Others are more moments that are finite. Hope it gives some hints to other solutions.

Comment: Perhaps you could illustrate your approach--which remains unclear--with a worked example?  (In so doing I suspect you will discover unexpected difficulties.)

Comment: The problem that needs to be addressed is;                 finding the parameters θi in the first equation given the later five constraint equations which are respectively the 'density function equation, the mean, the variance, the skewness and the kurtosis'.